# Crystal Reports: controlling cell padding using formula in cross tab

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crosstab

I am working on a **crystal report in VS 2012**. I have a cross-tab in it which is displaying required data. My problem is when I am getting less no. of rows, then its shifting upwards, leading a blank space in rest of the page.

Now, I want to set cell padding of cross-tab using some formula, so that I can increase some **vertical spacing of summarized fields** in order to make my report look better.

If anybody can tell me how to achieve this?

Here is a snap of my report:-

[Report Card](http://s9.postimg.org/ji8hqrvv3/Report_card.png)

Thanks,
Prakhar Mishra